# How can I return a string with @Url.Action

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

How can I return a model property with url and put it on onclick like that:

Model:

```
public class MyModel
{
     public string link {get;set;}
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    MyModel oMyModel = new MyModel();
    oMyModel.Link = "@Url.Action('" + "Index" + "', '" + "Users" + "')";

    return View(oMyModel);
}
```

In view:

```
 <a class="font" href="#" onclick="@Model.LINK">Click Here</a>
```

But in html it does not render corrently

Comment: model.Link = Url.Action(“actionName”,”controllerName”); this is the way to generate the url in your controller. For your case Link = Url.Action(“Index”,”Users”);

Comment: Also it would be `@Model.Link` (Case sensitive) Although you have three different cases for that link property!

Comment: Also, use the `href` attribute of the anchor tag!

Comment: It dont render correctly:the html result is <a class="child-font" href="#" onclick="Url.Action(&quot;Index&quot;,&quot;Cliente&quot;);">Visão Global</a>

Comment: Did you use what akd said?  That looks like you have kept your quotes around the url.action

Comment: Just copy the code I put above. Remove the quotation marks from your script.

Comment: In controller , Url is not recognized.   oMyModel.link= "Url.Action(\"Index\",\"Users\");";

Comment: it should be there - again, you need to remove the quotes and make sure you are using System.Web.Mvc;

Answer (score 0):

First, decide on a case. You're using `link` in your model, `Link` in your controller, and `LINK` in your view. In C#, those all mean different things. Choose one and make them all the same.

Second, the `@` notation is Razor syntax. You are adding it to a string and then using razor to inject *that string* into your view. But by that time, it's not going to get processed by Razor again, so it stays as `@Url.Action...`.

You should either do this in your controller, so it sets the variable to the actual URL (not just `"@Url.Action..."`):

```
oMyModel.Link = Url.Action("Index", "Users");
```

Or preferably, just call `Url.Action` in your view, which will give you the exact same result:

```
<a class="font" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Users")">Click Here</a>
```

Comment: But I want define url in controller and use in view.
In controller, URL is not recognized.

Comment: Make sure you're using the right case. It's `Url`, not `URL`. `Url.Action` is recognized in a controller. I just tried it.

Comment: `Url` is a property of `Controller`, so make sure your controller class is inheriting from `Controller` (although I don't know how your app could even work if it wasn't)

Comment: It only render onclick="/Users" , not onclick="/Users/Index" . 
Error: Invalid regular expression: missing /

Comment: The `Index` action is always the default, so "/Users" will use the `Index` action in the `Users` controller.

Comment: "Invalid regular expression"? Where are you using regular expressions?

Comment: Oh yeah, I guess you shouldn't be putting the URL in `onclick`. It should go in `href`. I've updated my answer to reflect that. The `onclick` attribute is for JavaScript.